Update python dictionary value as a list of strings enclosed within double quotes
I am trying to call a post request using python where the body is a dictionary in which one parameter has to change based on the values of a list.
The list is as below:
my_list = ['a14mnas','ty6798h']

The body for the api call is as below:
api_body = {
    "Page": 1,
    "Pages": 3,
    "Ids": []
}

I am trying to update the body as:
api_body["Ids"] = my_list[0]

which will update the body to
"Ids": ['a14mnas']

but I need the value in the list to be enclosed with double quotes as below:
"Ids": ["a14mnas"]

The api call takes only list with value enclosed with double quotes. How do I make the value to be in double quotes.
Tried adding ''' + to the string but it gives a single and double quote
''' + my_list[0] + '''

If I use this below code, I am able to get the post request to work just fine:
api_body = {
    "Page": 1,
    "Pages": 3,
    "Ids": ["a14mnas"]
}

myrequest = requests.post(api_url, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(api_body))

Where headers have the authentication token.While looping through the list to update the dict (key: Ids), how do I ensure that it takes the double quote?

Show your code.  Make a [mcve].  In particular, it sounds like the API wants a JSON body, which can be sent as r = requests.post(url, json=api_body).  It is JSON that requires double quotes in its encoded form.  The form shown will encode the Python object in JSON.

Remember that python dicts are not json, but can be converted extremely easily using the json module.  If you can't do Mark's idea, then you can convert a python dict to a JSON string with import json; api_body_json_str = json.dumps(api_body)

@mark tolonen: I have updated my question with the example that works

My bad, I just realized that Mark is using json = api_body. This change works!

Python allows definition of string literals with either single our double quotes - the result is identical. Python doesn't remember if you used single our double quotes when defining the string value, it's just a string value. When you use json.dumps to turn a dictionary with string values and keys into JSON text, Python will always use double quotes, because that is what JSON requires.
